# PHP: How to detect duplicate information processed from file?

Tags: php, string

I have text file with a bunch of text like:
`PLAYER_ENTERED name ipaddress username`
but there is other text in here

My code is as follows to extract the ipadress and username:

```
$q = $_REQUEST["ipladder"];
$f = fopen("ladderlog.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE)
{
    if (strstr($line, $q)) 
    {
        $data = explode(" ", $line); // split using the space into an array
                                     // array index 0 = PLAYER_ENTERED
        print "IP:" . $data[1] . "<br>";      // array index 1 = IP
        print "Name: " . $data[2];   // array index 2 = name
    }
}
```

The output is:
IP: ipaddress
Name: username

My question is... how to I prevent duplicate entries when the same occurrence appears in the file?

Comment: Are duplicates when any info is the same or when all info is the same?

Comment: when the output is the same, so ipaddress and username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is not too large and/or this is a local script. I would call `file()` to get the lines as an array and then `array_unique()`. Then you could loop over this array to print just the unique items.

```
$q = $_REQUEST["ipladder"];
$f = file("ladderlog.txt");
$f = array_unique($f);
foreach($f as $line)
{
    if (strstr($line, $q)) 
    {
        $data = explode(" ", $line); // split using the space into an array
                                     // array index 0 = PLAYER_ENTERED
        print "IP:" . $data[1] . "<br>";      // array index 1 = IP
        print "Name: " . $data[2];   // array index 2 = name
    }
}
```

Comment: the file is about 10MB, so it is kind of large

Comment: Eh, it's all relative. The above works in theory. But if performance is a problem for you, I'd suggest importing the file into a DB first, then using PHP.

Comment: array_unique(): The argument should be an array
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

the file needs to be an array first :(

Comment: See edit. I was still passing `file()` the arguments to `fopen()`

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3206208 bytes) I guess it was too big. Thanks for your help though, I've marked as best answer

Comment: Yeah, 10MB is a rather large file. I would suggest looking into a database solution instead of a flat file. Importing that to a DB is trivial as is examining/removing duplicates.